# Rendering a view with HtmlHelper and Partial Page in ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Hello in my project i have to implement Dynamic Menu using ASP.NET MVC3 Razor ..My menu structure is

1.UserManagement
 1.1Create new user
 1.2Create new Role 
2.Accounts
 2.1Income
 2.2Expense

For the above structure i have a layout page ( with css and scripts) and its working fine.
The problem is that in my view page menu is not displaying in a correct format
.there are two HtmlHelperExtensions one is for Main Menu and other is for Sub menu.Both are initialized in Menus.cshtml as partial page

```
@model IEnumerable<Elixir.Models.Menus>

<div>
    @Html.Raw(@Html.ParentMenus(Model))



    </div>

    <div>

    @Html.Raw(@Html.SubMenu(Model,3))
    </div>
```

**Updated Partial Code Code**

```
@model IEnumerable<Elixir.Models.Menus>


    @Html.Raw(@Html.ParentMenus(Model))

    @foreach (var menuitem in Model)
    {


        <div>
         @Html.Raw(@Html.ParentMenus(Model))
        </div>
        <div>
        @if (menuitem.MainMenuId == menuitem.MenuId)
        {
            int ab = Convert.ToInt32(menuitem.MainMenuId);
    @Html.Raw(@Html.SubMenu(Model, ab))
        }
    </div>

    }
```

> **How to call sub menu dynamically  when parent menu is called.Here am
>   explicitly assigning the Main Menu Id as "3" to Submenu.?**
>
> **How to connect parent Menus Html helper with submenu?**

**HtmlHelper Extension  Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using Elixir.Models;

namespace Elixir.HtmlHelpers
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static string ParentMenus(this HtmlHelper html,IEnumerable<Elixir.Models.Menus> menu)
        {
            string htmloutput=string.Empty;
            if (menu.Count() > 0)
            {
                htmloutput += "<ul class='side-navigation accordion' id='nav-accordion'>";
                var MainMenu = from mainMenu in menu where mainMenu.MainMenuId == null orderby mainMenu.MenuOrder select mainMenu;
                foreach (Menus m in MainMenu)
                {
                    htmloutput += "<li>";
                    htmloutput += "<li><i class='icon-home'>";
                    htmloutput += LinkExtensions.ActionLink(html, m.LinkName, m.ActionName, m.ControllerName);
                    htmloutput += "</li>";
                    htmloutput += "</li></i>";
                }
                htmloutput += "</ul>";
            }

            return htmloutput;

        }

        public static string SubMenu(this HtmlHelper html, IEnumerable<Menus> SubMenu, int MenuId)
        {
            string htmlOutput = string.Empty;
            if (SubMenu.Count() > 0)
            {
                htmlOutput += "<ul class='side-navigation accordion' id='nav-accordion'>";
                var subMenu = from SMenu in SubMenu where SMenu.MainMenuId == MenuId orderby SMenu.MenuOrder select SMenu;
                foreach (Menus m in subMenu)
                {
                    htmlOutput += "<li>";
                    htmlOutput += "<li><i class='icon-home'>";
                    htmlOutput += LinkExtensions.ActionLink(html, m.LinkName, m.ActionName, m.ControllerName);
                    htmlOutput += "</li>";
                    htmlOutput += "</li></i>";
                }
                htmlOutput += "</ul>";
            }
            return htmlOutput;
        }

    }
}
```

**My Index View Code**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Elixir ERP V1.0 Beta";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutUser.cshtml";
}
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div class="scroll-top">
            <a href="#" class="tip-top" title="Go Top"><i class="icon-arrow-up"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="left-bar merge-left">
            <!-- SEARCH BAR -->
            <!-- LEFT NAV -->
          @section leftnav{

             <div class="left-nav">
             @Html.Action("Menus");
  </div>



          }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop the menu items and pass in the `MainMenuId` like this:

```
@foreach(var menuItem in Model)
{

    <div>
    @Html.Raw(@Html.ParentMenus(menuItem))
    </div>
    <div>
    @Html.Raw(@Html.SubMenu(menuItem, menuItem.MainMenuId))
    </div>

}
```

Comment: Hello am getting for the above solution                         Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

Comment: Does it work when you hardcode the value 3 in as your original question? It could be a data or an issue with finding the Menus action.

Comment: Yes,Now i have updated the question with your logic,now there is no error but the menu is displaying all field values simultaneously.

Comment: Now i have changed the code that first div is taken out of the foreach loop.Now first div alone is working .

Comment: ya sure.but now the sub menus are not loading

Comment: There is no error ,but still i cant able to connect between the two static class means ,Parent Menu and Sub Menu